# Why deploy my rails app on heroku does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, deployment

I am new on Ruby/Rails application development. I already love Ruby/Rails because it's easy to learn. I've built an Rails application and i try to deploy on Heroku.
When i type :

```
heroku create
Creating app... done, stack is cedar-14
https://aqueous-plateau-17182.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/aqueous-plateau-17182.git
```

I don't have the following message :

```
Git remote heroku added
```

I think there is a problem with my remote :

```
git remote -v
heroku  git@bitbucket.org:pracede/hubapp.git (fetch)
heroku  git@bitbucket.org:pracede/hubapp.git (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:pracede/hubapp.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:pracede/hubapp.git (push)

git config --list | grep heroku
remote.heroku.url=git@bitbucket.org:pracede/hubapp.git
remote.heroku.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

1.There are remote but heroku refers to bitbucket. Is it correct ?
If no correct, how to do, please ?

2. I cannot deploy. I have the following message :

   git push heroku master
   Everything up-to-date

My rails application is not alive. Is someone could explain me, please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First delete the current remote heroku reference(i.e pointing to bitbucket remote ) with -

```
git remote rm heroku
```

Add then add heroku remote to your repo -

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:aqueous-plateau-17182.git
```

Hope this helps!